# Why there are two python versions in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I have created a virtual environment using anaconda in VS. When the environment is active. I check the version using `python --version`, it gives the following output `Python 3.9.9`, whereas when I use `which python` and check the version from the path `/usr/bin/python --version` I get a different version `Python 2.7.18`. Why is that happening, and which version does the environment use?

Comment: when you do  `/usr/bin/python --version` you force looking at in `/usr` so you get the python version of this location. If in front of your prompt you have like `(venv)` it is ok

Comment: so this means that the virtual environment uses `Python 3.9.9`?

Comment: obviously yes. try installing a specific lib in this virtual env that is not in the general and you will see. But I believe your virtual env is using python 3.9.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your virtual environment is activated the `python` command will use the python version from your venv (located in `path/to/.venv/bin/python`).
`which python` and `/usr/bin/python` forces the use of the python version installed in `/usr/bin/python` which in your case seems to be version 2.7.18. If you want to change your default Python version (the one thats used with `python` without a venv being active) you can use `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.9`.